# websockets and sync adapter in android

Tags: android, websocket, android-syncadapter, application-design

I'm designing an application for getting some data from a web service, like a REST API and showing it to the user:

I was thinking about using the Sync Adapter with Content Provider API:

1. the Sync Adapter handles the data flow between the local DB and remote DB.
2. the content provider API loads the data into the UI.

My question is that the remote application, if, has a server push support (using Socket.IO or so), how should I design the app to exploit this feature? because as far as I understand, when the SyncAdapter will run is determined by SyncManager. So I can't ensure that the sync is done only when the server pushes. I wanted to know if this is possible, even without running the application in the foreground or background. i.e., only with the sync adapter running.

thanks in advance for any replies.

PS: I'm just starting to design android apps, so forgive me/correct me if I'm wrong.

Follow up:

1. I'm not interested in the Cloud messaging APIs (like GCM). I wanted to keep the data private if the user wishes to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your application will be running for a while you don't really want to keep a constant connection open to a server since that will eat a lot of batteries.

It sounds like you're looking for this:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Using gcm your app can get a notification when there's an update on your server.

Comment: I've been asked to look at GCM before, but I don't want the data to be passing through the google servers (or any other as a matter of fact). What if the user wishes to keep the data private, shouldn't we keep it that way and be discrete? Also don't tell me to encrypt the data, that seems to be an overkill.

Comment: I've updated the question to opt out the cloud messaging APIs too. thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can still use gcm to only tell your app that there is new data waiting on the server. Then let your app make a connection to your server and get the data. This way the data itself will never go through gcm.

Comment: that means the server should be responding with the message right? if it is, then the normal case is that i wont have the control over the server so that way wont work too.

Comment: Also the GCM makes the application to access only one server/domain. but my app lets the user to select it themselves. so that would render the GCM pretty useless in this case.

Comment: I think this may be the best way available. I was wrong about the way GCM worked.